# Typescript: Type not assignable to another

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following functions:

```
        async validateForm(): Promise<void> {
            const validations = this.getValidations(this.userForm.inputs)

            if (!Object.keys(validations).length) return

            const { data } = await FormService.validateFormOrInput({
                validations,
                values: this.userData,
            })

            if (!data) {
                this.formErrors = {}
                return
            }

            this.setErrors(data.errors)
        },
        getValidations(inputs: Input[]): Validations {
            const validations: Validations = {}

            inputs.forEach((input: Input): void => {
                if (input.validation) {
                    validations[input.key] = input.validation
                }
            })

            return validations
        },
```

And their respective types are:

```
export interface Validations {
    [key: string]: string[]
}

export interface ValidationPayload {
    validations: Validations
    values: {
        [key: string]: string | boolean | []
    }
}
```

And the `validateFormOrInput` function looks like this:

```
    async validateFormOrInput(
        payload: PayloadType<ValidationPayload>
    ): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        const data = (await this.post(
            '/api/form/validate',
            payload
        )) as ValidationResult
        return data
    }

export interface PayloadType<T> {
    [key: string]: T
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:
[image]

Can someone experienced in Typescript explain this? I think it has something to do with PayloadType but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you,

Comment: Ensure that the return types of your functions match what you're expecting. In your case, validateForm is declared as an async function that returns `Promise<void>`. Make sure that all paths within the function return a `Promise<void>`.

Comment: how about you change ```Promise<ValidationResult>``` to just ```ValidationResult```

Comment: @cantdocpp, that cannot be done. Async functions require a Promise<T> type